# How to have Tiled Galleries like in WordPress.com?

Tags: gallery, plugin-jetpack

In a WordPress.com hosted blog, you have the posibility to create picture galleries with a different style than usual: tiles, squared tiles or circles.

What plugin are they using to achieve this? I haven't found that feature in a stand-alone WordPress installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiled galleries have been proprietary feature of wordpress.com, but later also released as [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) feature since [version 2.1](http://jetpack.me/2013/01/04/galleries/) of it.